# skip lines after sed regular expression match

Tags: regex, bash, nginx, sed, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to edit an aws elasticbeanstalk nginx config file using `sed`. I would like to insert a new location block after the default one.

To do this I'm matching a line in the previous location block and then I would like to skip down 8 lines and then insert the text.

This is what it looks like before I run sed

```
upstream nodejs {
    server 127.0.0.1:8081;
    keepalive 256;
}

server {
    listen 8080;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://nodejs;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

}
```

and here is my naive attempt at constructing the command which doesn't actually work but instead just sticks the new block under the line containing `proxy_pass  http://nodejs;`.

```
sed -i '/nodejs;/a \ location ^~ /blog {}' /etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf
```

How can I skip 8 lines after the line I identify in my `regex`. Also suggestions on another way to identify where I want to place my new block are appreciated as well.

Comment: Could you post what the new config should look like?

Comment: can you rely on the indention of the `}` below the location. or of the final `}`?  I think something more advanced like `awk` may be a better fit to this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks for `nodejs;` and jumps eight lines down and then inserts `location ^~ /blog {}`.  You haven't shown your desired output but, based on the question, I infer that this is what you are looking for:

```
$ sed '/nodejs;/ {n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;s/^/    location ^~ \/blog {}\n/}' file
upstream nodejs {
    server 127.0.0.1:8081;
    keepalive 256;
}

server {
    listen 8080;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://nodejs;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location ^~ /blog {}
}
```

#### How it works

The sed command is:

`/nodejs;/ {n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;s/^/    location ^~ \/blog {}\n/}`

This starts by looking for lines containing `nodejs;` and, when found, executes the statements in braces which follow.

`n` prints the current pattern space and reads in the next line.  We do this eight times.  This has the effect of jumping down eight lines.

`s/^/    location ^~ \/blog {}\n/` makes the changes on the eighth line.